# Splitter using jQUery UI library

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create resizable cells (Splitter) like the one below 
http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html

But I need to do that using jQUery UI.

I am not sure how similar thing can be achieved using jQUery UI.

Is it possible using the jQuery UI Resiable(http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

If yes, could you please provide any reference example for the same.
It should behave similar to the Methvin.com/splitter

Answer (score 4):

This is the code I used one day:

```
$(".resizable1").resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    minWidth: '50',
    maxWidth: '350',
    resize: function() {
        var remainingSpace = $(this).parent().width() - $(this).outerWidth(),
            divTwo = $(this).next(),
            divTwoWidth = remainingSpace - (divTwo.outerWidth() - divTwo.width());
        divTwo.width(divTwoWidth);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/

Comment: Source: http://www.codechewing.com/library/jquery-ui-resizable-splitter-function/

Comment: This example is great! How about to use $(".resizable2").resizable with handles: 'w'? I  try to rewrite the "resize: function()" but it couldn't work properly. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @dfsq ur example is great and its working, but i am trying this same idea with multiple number of columns. where we should deduct sum of  previous columns width also, for getting  `remainingSpace`. here i'm facing some pblms.. if u have some brilliant idea or reference, it will save my hours.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with the jquery ui, check out the docs here http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#helper this is just a short hand example

```
$(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      handles: "n,e,s,w" // chose the handle you want
    });
  });
```