# jquery ui: resize also triggers a resize on `window`

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I've found this nice splitter here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319834/splitter-using-jquery-ui-library) ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/)).
Because all the sizes are set in pixels it is not very response. So I changed them to percentages ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/739/)). Now, if you move the splitter, and next try to change the window size it still breaks.

In order to fix this I tried adding a listener on the window object

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    /* reset width of both elements to percentages */
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/738/)

This code should only be triggered when the window size changes. Unfortunately, it is also called when jquery-ui triggers the 'resize' event. 
Any suggestions how to stop the propagation of that event when triggered by jquery-ui ?

If there is already a responsive splitter, please let me know!

Comment: event.stopPropagation() may help

Comment: You might think that, but that didn't work, checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/738/) jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to trigger the code only when window resizes, you can try using e.target.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/8qzTJ/740/

```
$(function () {
var el1, el2;

$(".resizable1").resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    minWidth: '50',
    resize: function (event) {
        var remainingSpace = $(this).parent().width() - $(this).outerWidth(),
            divTwo = $(this).next(),
            divTwoWidth = remainingSpace - (divTwo.outerWidth() - divTwo.width());
        divTwo.width(divTwoWidth);
        el1 = $(this);
        el2 = divTwo;

        event.stopPropagation();
        //event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});

$(window).on('resize', function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target).hasClass('ui-resizable'));
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('ui-resizable')) {//Check whether the target has class "ui-resizable".
        console.log('window');
        if (el1 && el2) {
            el1.width('50%');
            el2.width('50%');
        }
    }
 });
});
```

Here before executing the resize function, I am checking whether  the target has class "ui-resizable". jQuery adds a class "ui-resizable" on the binding elements. Hope this helps.

Comment: absolutely. But do you have an explanation why this event cannot be stopped ?

Comment: thanks a lot, with that link I was able to solve it ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/741/))